# There is already an object error after database is dropped

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, windows

Started learning SQL Server and stuck with this simple code:

```
drop database if exists dbo;

create database dbo;

create table dbo.a_table (a_table_a_field   int not null);
```

Running it twice in SSMS gives: "There is already an object named 'a_table' in the database."

Seems that I do it in completely wrong way. Please, help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve created a database called `dbo` but you’re creating the table in the current database. Try adding this before the create table statement:

```
USE dbo;
```

I might choose a different database name, too. `dbo` has specific meaning in SQ Server.

Comment: This helps! But if I create dbo.something, doesn't it already mean that new table is to be created inside dbo? So, the dot in the name of table has no special meaning?

Comment: @Leonid This is why I suggested not naming your *database* `dbo`. An object has a hierarchy: **server** dot **database** dot **schema** dot **object**. I can create a table called `dbo.foo` in *any* database. It is in the `dbo` schema, but unlike other platforms, schema <> database.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit:

In SQL Server, whenever you specify a table name, you can provide three parts.* There's the database name, the schema name, and then the table name.

Every database has a `dbo` schema by default. Users of a database generally can have a schema with their username, and you can create schemas to group tables that "belong" together.

Every database connection has a default database, and a default schema. The initial default database is either based on the SQL login used to establish the connection, or is set when making the connection. The current database can be changed with the `USE <databasename>;` command.

The default schema for the current database is set in the user account currently being used in the database (most often an account tied to the user's login, though it's possible to change that, for instance with the `EXECUTE AS` command/clause). As far as I can tell, the current schema can only be changed (temporarily) by changing the user you're operating as, or (permanently) by changing the default schema for the user; there's no equivalent I've found for the `USE` command when it comes to schemas. *Caveat*: it appears that logins with the `sysadmin` server role, users with the `db_owner` database role, and the actual login that owns the database with always have the default schema `dbo` in that database (or, for `sysadmin`, in all databases).

When you need to reference a table, the only value that's explicitly required is the table name itself (barring tables on linked servers). If the table exists in the current database and the current schema, those can be ignored.

You can use the functions `DB_NAME()` and `SCHEMA_NAME()` to confirm the current database and schema, if in doubt.

For the example below, assume that `SELECT DB_NAME(), SCHEMA_NAME()` returns `MyDB` and `MySchema` for the example below; further, assume the current user has the default schema `schema2` in another database, `YourDB`:

- `MyTable` => `MyDB.MySchema.MyTable`
- `MySchema.MyTable` => `MyDB.MySchema.MyTable`
- `MyDB.MySchema.MyTable` => `MyDB.MySchema.MyTable`
- `MyDB..MyTable` => `MyDB.MySchema.MyTable`
- `dbo.MyTable` => `MyDB.dbo.MyTable`
- `YourDB.schema2.MyTable` => `YourDB.schema2.MyTable`
- `YourDB..MyTable` => `YourDB.schema2.MyTable`
- `YourDB.dbo.MyTable` => `YourDB.dbo.MyTable`

So, to do what you wanted to, your code should have been:

```
drop database if exists dbo;

create database dbo;

create table dbo.dbo.a_table (a_table_a_field   int not null);
```

Or, as noted in others answers:

```
drop database if exists dbo;

create database dbo;

USE dbo;

create table dbo.a_table (a_table_a_field   int not null);
```

* If you're using a linked server, there are four parts; the first must be the linked server name, then the three parts mentioned above.